# 301 redirect generating a configuration 500 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this .htaccess file that I uploaded to the server. It used to work, but now that I added these lines it gives an error.

This is the log file error:

```
[Tue Apr 29 12:18:58 2014] [10600395] [core:alert] [client 74.64.0.36:62143] /var/chroot/home/content/95/10600395/html/superior/.htaccess: Invalid command '[L,R=301,NC]', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/wp-admin/tools.php?page=redirection.php
```

The only changes I made was to add these lines:

```
RewriteRule ^page2\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/superior-maintenance-services-llc/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page3\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/services/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page4\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/contact-superior-maintenance-services-llc/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page6\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-floor-cleaning/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page7\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-office-cleaning-michigan/ [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page8\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-power-washing-michigan/ [L,R=301,NC]  
RewriteRule ^page9\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-carpet-cleaning-michigan/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

And here is the error I get:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

Here is the full .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page2\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/superior-maintenance-services-llc/ [L,R=301,NC]    
RewriteRule ^page3\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/services/  [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page4\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/contact-superior-maintenance-services-llc/ [L,R=301,NC]    
RewriteRule ^page5\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-cleaners-michigan/
  [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page6\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-floor-cleaning/ [L,R=301,NC]    
RewriteRule ^page7\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-office-cleaning-michigan/  [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^page8\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-power-washing-michigan/ [L,R=301,NC]    
RewriteRule ^page9\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-carpet-cleaning-michigan/  [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN wtwp_cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>

    # Text
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xml .xml

    # Image
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz

    # Video
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe

    # PDF
    AddType application/pdf .pdf

    # Flash
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf

    # Font
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf

    # Audio
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma

    # Zip/Tar
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On

    # Text
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600

    # Image
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000

    # Video
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000

    # PDF
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000

    # Flash
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000

    # Font
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000

    # Audio
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000

    # Zip/Tar
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|htm|html|rtf|rtx|txt|xml|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|svg|svgz|asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|mov|qt|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf|mp3|m4a|ogg|wav|wma|tar|gz|gzip|zip)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
        Header unset ETag
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:css|js|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png|pdf|swf|ttf|ttc|eot|otf)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset Set-Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END wtwp_cache

# BEGIN wtwp_security
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<Files "wp-config.php">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
Options -Indexes
# END wtwp_security
```

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log to see what the error is?

Comment: @anubhava I just updated the original question with the log file error. Than you for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `[L,R=301,NC]` in a new line which is wrong syntax. Put them in one line:

```
RewriteRule ^page5\.html$ http://superiormaintenanceservices.com/commercial-cleaners-michigan/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: thank you. I did see that I have a new line in there. I fixed that but I still get the error. I also saw that you took out the 301 that appears right after the beginning of the line. Was that a syntax mistake on my part?

Comment: Yes stray `[L,R=301,NC]` had to be removed from new line. If you're still getting 500 then check Apache error.log again

Comment: I still get the same error even after that got fixed. Any idea what might be wrong still?

Comment: As I suggested if you're still getting 500 then check Apache error.log again.

Comment: I meant that I fixed the syntax error we discussed, and checked the log, and I still get that error :)

Comment: That means somewhere either this .htaccess or `httpd.conf` another stray string like this still exists.

Comment: yes you were right. There was still a hidden character in there somewhere - thank you :)